# How to solve system of equations containing summation over variable to solve for?

Tags: summation, systems-of-equations

How do we solve for $\pi_i$ in the following?
$$\pi_i=\frac{\sum\limits_j N_{i,j}}{\sum\limits_j\left( \ell_{i,j} \frac{\sum\limits_k N_{k,j}}{\sum\limits_k \ell_{k,j} \pi_k}\right)}\qquad\forall i,\qquad \sum\limits_i \pi_i=1.$$

Answer (score 0):

Assume $\pi_i$ where $i \in \{1,2,\cdots ,I\}$, you have $I$ equations in the form you gave plus the the equation with sum over $\pi_i$, so you can remove on of the $I$ equations, then you will have:
$$
A *\Pi = b
$$
where $A$ is the $I\times I$ identity matrix with the last row where all elements are replaced by ones, $\Pi$ is the vector you are solving for with size $I\times 1$, and $b$ is a vector with size $I\times 1$ with the elements on the right except the last element is $1$.

Then, you can solve it by any technique you prefer.

Comment: This looks correct. How does one go about removing one of the equations?

Comment: In this case, we have $I+1$ equations and only $I$ variables. This means that one equation is redundant, then you can remove any equation you want. I just chose to discard the equation for $\pi_I$ (the last equation), but you can discard any of them.

Comment: I know it's redundant and that you can discard one of the variables, but how do you actually use that equation to derive an expression for one of the $\pi_i$ in terms of the remaining variables? Or how is that expression incorporated in the matrix equation given above? This is what I am confused about.

Comment: Not why you can remove one of the equations, but how

Comment: what "remaining variables"?

Comment: say you use the redundant equation to remove $\pi_3$, then there are still $\pi_1, \pi_2, \pi_4,...$ to solve for

Comment: Still, $b$ contains reference to $\Pi$ at an awkward place. I just don't see how to solve for it analytically.